# How to set paint.setColor(R.color.white)

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I have a custom View that uses Paint and Canvas to draw objects. My question is how to set:

```
int color = R.color.white;
paint.setColor(color);
```

from my /res/valuse/color.xml which includes resources like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    ...
</resources>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white);
paint.setColor(color);
```

The `setColor()` method takes a color number as `int` value, but not a resource id which is an `int` as well.

Comment: [Resources documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)) says _This method was deprecated in API level 23_, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31590927/4281182).

Comment: Agree, this is an important notice.

Comment: @SelçukCihan, I edited this answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 14):

first get your color from xml file

```
int color = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary); // old
```

is deprecated now, use this instead

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary); // new
```

set color

```
paint.setColor(color);
```

xml file preview: res/values/color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Saved me from hours of searching the web dealing with API compatibility issues here.

Answer (score 11):

Try using `color.white`:

```
paint.setColor(Color.white)
```

Comment: hmm ... looks like this doesn't answer the question (at least not how I understand it :-) - which is about how to access a custom color declared in the resources (vs. a pre-defined color)

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is to get the int value of a color predefinied from *resources* for use with paint.setColor(...). And it should be Color.WHITE (all caps), not Color.white. Completely useless.

Answer (score 2):

```
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Set any color

```
paint.setColor( Color.rgb(R, G, B) )
```